# How can iterate a json object string with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have web service which return json string like : 
d={"main0ID":"abc.es/main","main1ID":"ah/main"}
I wanna append this to ul HTML control. How to iterate over json object string and append to ul?

Thanks...

Comment: Use For...In loop http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for_in.asp

Comment: using w3schools is an atrocity. So much misinformation on that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have ul like this

```
<ul id="ulItems"></ul>
```

This will get the items from JSON and add to UL

```
$(function(){
    var items="";
    var data={"main0ID":"abc.es/main","main1ID":"ah/main"}
       $.each(data,function(index,item){
         items+="<option value='"+item+"'>"+item+"</option>";
       });       
    $("#ulItems").html(items);
});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/tFpTu/4/

Always build a string and call the `html` function only once instead of calling the `append` function **n times inside a loop**

Answer (score 3):

You could use `for..in` to iterate an object.

```
for (var key in d) {
  console.log(key, d[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) or [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to iterate over the json object.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $.ajax({           
                url: 'your url'
                type : 'POST',
                data : {/*any data*/},
                dataType:'json',
                success: function(msg) { //your json return
                for (i=0;i<msg.length;i++){
       alert(msg[i]['your_index']);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both this methods can be used
But first method is considerably fast...

Check [**this tutorial**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/10-ways-to-instantly-increase-your-jquery-performance/) ...

```
for (var keyIndex in d) {
    console.log(keyIndex, d[keyIndex]);
}

$.each(data,function(keyIndex,value){
    console.debug(inkeyIndexex,value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Button1").click(function () {
WebService.GetList(OnComplete, OnError);
function OnComplete(result) 
{
var items = "";
var value = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.deserialize(result, true);
for (var property in value) 
{              
items += "<option value='" + value[property] + "'>" + value[property] + "</option>";
}
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ListBox1").html(items);
}
function OnError(err)
{
alert("The error is :" + err.get_Message());
}
});
```